# In rails, using jquery token input and the tags are not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-tokeninput

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author_tokens, "Authors" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :author_tokens, "data-pre"=> @article.authors.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
  </div>
```

This is my field for tokens. all authors name is listed here sucessfully. But when I choose them they are not copied in textarea author_tokens. but other name beside the option are copied in textfield.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"4XajxI5Cw59/Oe/Di0vlZKG2wp61/plh12iIs+OrKaI=",
 "article"=>{"name"=>"fdsfds",
 "published_on(1i)"=>"2012",
 "published_on(2i)"=>"8",
 "published_on(3i)"=>"21",
 "author_tokens"=>"",
 "content"=>"fdsfsfds"},
 "commit"=>"Create Article"}
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this in your html.erb file.

```
<% f.text_field :name_of_the_date_column, :value=>Date.today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), :id=>"dp5" %>
```

and in apllication.js file

```
$("#dt5").datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    })
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
  $('#dt5').datepicker('hide');
});
```

This works for me